# How to vertical scroll in Android Activity

Tags: android, scroll

I have the following layout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:isScrollContainer="true"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <Gallery
        android:id="@+id/gallery"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="bottom" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/chart"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal" />
    
</LinearLayout>
```

Gallery is filled at runtime and when the user taps on an item I fill the LinearLayout with a series of images.
I would like to scroll vertically but if I add a ScrollView when the user taps the Gallery the LinearLayout is not filled anymore.

Is it normal? How can I add a vertical scroll?

Comment: Could you explain a bit more what's happening when you add the ScrollView?

Comment: When i add the ScrollView as root element, when the user taps on a gallery item nothing happens and the linear layout is not filled with the View content; i tried to debug and objects are correctly handled but when i do layout.addView(newView...) the View is not shown

Comment: are you doing setContentView(R.id.my_layout) and then trying to wrap that in a ScrollView? I'm not sure why you are calling addView.

Comment: I make setContentView(R.layout.my_layout), then 
LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.chart); 
and i dynamically add content to it with
layout.addView(mChartView, new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
         LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));

Answer (score 13):

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent">
<ScrollView android:id="@+id/ScrlView" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
 <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/layoutForScroll" android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"        
    >
   <Gallery android:id="@+id/gallery"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="bottom"/>
  <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/chart" android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"          
    android:layout_weight="1" />
</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your vertical scroll view can only have one child, which means you need to envelop your gallery view and the linear view "chart" with another linerLayout which then should be enveloped with a scrollView.

When you add your new views, you may need to refresh the drawable state of the scroll view or invalidate it, try something like that, so that it expands accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You have to extend the Gallery class and in the Draw procedure rotate the canvas for 90 degrees. Then just a few adoptions like modifying the onTouch event and a few more is required. After this there will be a few problems with the layout (since it still wants to draw in the layout in its parameters). So I put it inside a LinearLayout and fixed the layout size in that.
So the final vertical gallery is actually a linear layout which has a gallery put inside it. I have implemented it, and it works quite well. You will only need to rotate everything you put in it for 90 degrees to the other direction. The trade off is really a little thus you can extend every view you want to put inside it and just rotate it to the other direction in the draw procedure.