# android make a radio button scrollable

Tags: android, radio-button, scrollbar

I have a problem with rather large radio button text. The text for these radio buttons is generated dynamically. Unfortunately sometimes there is allot of text and this pushes down the other objects in my layout. I though if I could make the radio button scrollable then this would remove this issue. What I mean by scrollable is that if the text length is beyond a certain size a scroll bar on the side of the radio button appears so the user can scroll through the text of the radio button without altering the layout of the rest of my xml file. When I mean altering layout other widgets are pushed further down eg a button. This is the xml layout file layout for the radio buttons.

```
 <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="217dp"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <RadioGroup
            android:id="@+id/radioGroup1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="212dp"
            android:layout_weight="6.86" >

           <ScrollView
               android:id="@+id/ScrlView"
               android:layout_width="fill_parent"
               android:layout_height="78dp" >

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/radio1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="79dp"
                android:checked="true"
                android:text="RadioButton"
                android:textSize="16dp" />
             </ScrollView>
            <ScrollView
                android:id="@+id/ScrlView"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="74dp" >

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/radio2"
                android:layout_width="304dp"
                android:layout_height="75dp"
                android:text="RadioButton" />
              </ScrollView>

               <ScrollView android:id="@+id/ScrlView" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/radio3"
                android:layout_width="300dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:text="RadioButton" />
            </ScrollView>

        </RadioGroup>
    </LinearLayout>
```

I checked this link and though I might try and add a scroll view for the radio group so if a radio question is too long the user can scroll down. 
[How to vertical scroll an activity in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5393776/how-to-vertical-scroll-an-activity-in-android)

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by making the radio buttons scrollable?

Answer (score 0):

Try a TableLayout and tell us what you get.  Place each radio button in its own table row.  You should also be aware that the setText() should also accept a SpannableStringBuilder as input.  This might give you more control over how the text is formatted.  Lastly I think you need to think a bit about design.  I mean there are limits!  If you get too much text perhaps you don't show all of it.  Look at online newspapers.  They have the same problem.  Can't show everything all the time.

Comment: they are answers to questions and some answers are longer then others. There are a few exceptions and these cause there to be a display issue with the radio button. Nearly all the text is displayed but some is cut off due to size issues.

Comment: i updated my post to use scrollview but for some reason i cannot scroll through my radio buttons text.